# ActiveX - still able to sign this?

Tags: dll, asp-classic, activex

Im using an old Classic ASP application and for a custommer we need to have 
signed ActiveX controls.

After searching i found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231196(v=vs.60).aspx but the links below in the examples of microsoft are dead.

Is there still a company that provide ActiveX certificates? and are we still able to sign them using VB6 Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symantec claims to issue Authenticode certificates. And their website specifically mentions ActiveX controls. I haven't tested it myself, as I haven't needed ActiveX in a long time.

https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode

Comment: Oh, and if it's an internal project, which at this point I'd assume it has to be, you can also use self-signed certificates as long as you distribute them to all your workstations.

Comment: Sadly it isn't internaly its for a Company in Healtcare. Thanks for you effort